# Transmission-daemon cannot write to folder

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I believe a picture paints a thousand words, so here it is:

[image]

As can be seen for the screenshot, debian-transmission is part of the users group that has write access to "complete" and "incomplete" folders.

But I'm getting this error when trying to download something.

(this is a screenshot from transmission remote gui)

[image]

I have no problems if I change the folder owner to "debian-transmission" but I thought members of the "users" group should be able to write to it as well.

My normal user "yomi" doesn't have a problem writing to "incomplete" folder.

[image]